# visual basic 6.0 comm port code error

Tags: vb6, serial-port, client-server

I am actually trying to get data from `port1` but the error `Invalid port number` is generated.

The code is:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    MsgBox ("The port is open " & MSComm1.PortOpen)
    If (MSComm1.PortOpen = False) Then
    MSComm1.PortOpen = True
    End If
    Command1.Enabled = False
    Command2.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    If (MSComm1.PortOpen = True) Then
    MSComm1.PortOpen = False
    End If
    Command1.Enabled = True
    Command2.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    With MSComm1
    .CommPort = 1
    .RThreshold = 1
    .RTSEnable = True
    .Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
    .InputLen = 127
    .SThreshold = 1
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    If (MSComm1.PortOpen = True) Then
    MSComm1.PortOpen = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
    Dim Buffer As String

    Select Case MSComm1.CommEvent
    Case comEvReceive
    'Text1.Text = " "
    Buffer = MSComm1.Input
    Text1.Text = Text1.Text & Buffer
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you get when you click on the "Debug" button?

Comment: Maybe you don't have COM port 1 on your system. Check your system settings.

Comment: @Csharp invalid port number

Answer (score 1):

Try different COM port. A number between 1 and 16 is acceptable.

```
' Open the serial port
MSComm1.CommPort = 2
MSComm1.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
MSComm1.PortOpen = True
```

**"The CommPort property sets which serial port to open. Assuming that a modem is connected to COM2, the above example sets the value to 2 (COM2) and connects to the modem. You can set the CommPort property value to any number between 1 and 16 (the default is 1). If, however, you set this value to a COM port that does not exist for the system on which your application is run, an error will be generated."**

Sauce: [dx.eng.uiowa.edu/eedesign/MScomm.doc](http://dx.eng.uiowa.edu/eedesign/MScomm.doc)

Comment: sir i tried it,i have com1 port and stil i am finding error,please i kindly request u to help me in this issue

Comment: why should i write """"mscomm1.portopen=true"""

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the code i posted in the following answer :

[search for available com ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661612/how-might-i-retrieve-the-port-number-of-a-usb-device-that-is-connected-to-a-usb/13972265#13972265)

running that code will give you a list of available com ports

use it in your code, and let your code select a com port from that list

Comment: sir , i checked that but am getting the following error-method or data member not found(highlited word is checkport in "Select Case CheckPort(intIndex)"

Comment: sorry it seems i forgot some spaces when posting the code .. i edited it now so that it shows as 1 big code block ..

Comment: did you also copy the CheckPort function ?

Comment: sir sir, stil am having an error of 8002 thats why am getting  only two options- not used and in use ,selecting either of them doesnt do ![image after running the program][1] do anything,pls  kindly request you to help me

Comment: actually what happens is after checking comm1.portopen=true it goes to errorfound

Comment: still i couldnt understand how could this code tackle 8002 error,am stil having the 8002 error even in your program,i didnt connect any hardware while running this code,should i?,once i connected hardware and tried running,the same error was created

Comment: pls help me with ths issue @Hrqls

Comment: pls help me with this issue

Comment: @George  wud u  please help me

Comment: sir since u have the code can u make it as a project and upload,maybe my mistake in that wilbe rason for error

Comment: if you only get error 8002, then you don't have a com port on your system .... do you see any ports when you look in your system : control panel - system - devicemanager - ports (com & lpt) .... the terms might be slightly different because i manually translated them from my dutch system

Comment: but stil am getting  some junk values

Comment: please accept this answer as the answer to the question of this thread. the junk values are addressed in your other question.