# How to write a code using visual basic 6 to detect serial port connected or disconnected?

Tags: vba

I am new to visual basic 6 and I would like to write a code that can detect if serial port com1 is connected then the application will automatically close.

Thanks and appreciated your help!

Comment: Do you have some code you can show us?

Comment: Your question says VB6.  Your tag says VBA.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, like it's already said in the comments, you surely mean VB6 and not VBA.

Without any code it's difficult to give you a good answer. But I will try..

There is a MSComm Control in VB6 which is useful for serial communication. You can check the property 'PortOpen'

```
MSComm1.CommPort = 1
If MSComm1.PortOpen = False Then
    Unload Me
End If
```

For further information check this question:

[Problems opening and closing the mscomm port in vb6 when interfacing microcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105223/problems-opening-and-closing-the-mscomm-port-in-vb6-when-interfacing-microcontro)

and see this documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259393(v=vs.60).aspx